# Params sent to external library declared but never used

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using the [jsoendermann/rn-section-list-get-item-layout](https://github.com/jsoendermann/rn-section-list-get-item-layout) npm package to help me define the `getItemLayout` property to **[SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html)**. I need to define the `getItemLayout` property to get `scrollToLocation()` to work.

The documentation states that it should be used like this:

```
import sectionListGetItemLayout from 'react-native-section-list-get-item-layout'

// cut..

    this.getItemLayout = sectionListGetItemLayout({
      // The height of the row with rowData at the given sectionIndex and rowIndex
      getItemHeight: (rowData, sectionIndex, rowIndex) =>
                                                    sectionIndex === 0 ? 100 : 50,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SectionList
        {...otherStuff}
        getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

The TypeScript (2.5.3) compiler complains about this line:

**getItemHeight: (rowData, sectionIndex, rowIndex) => sectionIndex === 0 ? 100 : 50,**

`error TS6133: 'rowData' is declared but never used.
error TS6133: 'rowIndex' is declared but never used.`

I guess both `rowData` and `rowIndex` are used internally in the npm package, but how do I tell that to the TS compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Convincing the compiler that `rowData` and `sectionIndex` are used elsewhere would probably be futile, as the error is that they arent used in this particular function.

Per https://www.triplet.fi/blog/typescript-getting-rid-of-error-x-is-declared-but-never-used/, the solution is to replace `rowData` and `sectionIndex` with a `{}`, which gets rid of an argument name, thus eliminating an unused argument.